# Optimize window length (STFT) via gradient descent (in neural networks)

Tags: window-functions, stft, optimization, neural-network

The authors from [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiHp_Ti8Yv2AhXMSvEDHd9SD3kQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F2010.15049&usg=AOvVaw0ldyNKjVYhJ43_gi40XEyF) optimized a Gaussian window size via gradient descent (the σ parameter of the bell curve) together with the other parameters of neural networks.

I don't use Gaussian window but use Hann window instead. I would like to know how to optimize stft window size with Hann/Hamming window via gradient descent?

The problem is that unlike the Gaussian window, Hann window does not have continuous parameter σ as a proxy for gradient descent. Is there a way to rewrite Hann window or are there parameters that one could use to control the window size and that are differentiable? Currently the $n$ is positive integer and is not differentiable.

torch.hann_window uses:

$$w[n] = \begin{cases}
\tfrac{1}{2} \left( 1 − \cos \left(\tfrac{2\pi}{N-1}n\right) \right) \qquad & 0 \le n \le N-1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$

I scratched my head for quite some time but could not figure out how to differentiate it.

Any hints from you are highly appreciated.

Comment: In the optimization effort, what parameter are they trying to maximize or minimize by varying the window width?

Comment: And with the Gaussian window, there are two width parameters to think about.  1.  the $\sigma$ parameter of the bell curve.  2. the actually cutoff point where the window goes to zero.

Comment: Yes, the σ parameter of the bell curve.

Comment: Well, if you have an optimum $\sigma$ for the optimum Gaussian, then you can fit a Hann or Hamming to it so that the second-derivative of the main lobe in the middle is the same for both the Hann and the optimal Gaussian.

Comment: I am not planning to find the optimum σ for Gaussian (this is what was done in the paper) but would like to optimize Hann. Are you suggesting to use the optimum σ of Gaussian to optimize Hann indirectly?

Comment: Yes.  Because I do not have the foggiest idea what specific parameter you're trying to minimize or maximize in choosing the optimal $\sigma$ for a Gaussian window.  So, without that knowledge, if your problem is solved for Gaussian, I am suggesting that you could consider that whatever optimal Gaussian window you get, you choose the Hann (or Hamming) window that has the same height and same curvature for the main lobe.  That means the values of the zeroth, first, and second derivatives are the same in the center of both windows.  They might have approximately the same performance.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson many thanks for completing the formula and sharing the idea! I edited my question to be more precise. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson the paper used Gaussian window as an example to show that the window size could be optimized via gradient descent but I don't use Gaussian window at all. Do you know if there are other parameters that controls the window width of Hann window and are differentiable? If directly optimizing Hann window is possible, it would be better than taking a detour via Gaussian window optimization. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no other parameter to the Hann window other than its width.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to take STFT using operators with autodiff support, e.g. via PyTorch. Then simply set the window as an updatable parameter, initializing as Hanning etc:

```
import torch.nn as nn
from scipy.signal import windows

win = torch.from_numpy(windows.hann(128))
win_t = nn.Parameter(win, requires_grad=True)
```

Then we'd do e.g.

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = STFT(x, win_t)
    x = self.conv(x)
    ...
```

It might help to apply a symmetry constraint, by e.g. defining weights of the window as only half of the initial window, but operating with the full window that uses the updated weights.

See [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78531/50076) for example with fully differentiable CWT applied on inversion. That network could be embedded in a conv net and its filter weights updated if we wrap them with `nn.Parameter`.

#### Optimizing for width

If the goal's to optimize a parameter of a predefined window function, then generate the window through the differentiable parameter:

```
def gauss(N, sigma):
    t = torch.linspace(-.5, .5, N)
    return torch.exp(-(t / sigma)**2)

N = x.shape[-1]
sigma = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.1))
win_t = gauss(N, sigma)
```

#### Optimizing for length

To optimize for the number of samples of the window, we must ensure the sampling is differentiable.

- Hann does `arange(N) / N`, but `N` must be continuous, which requires rounding. `torch.round` isn't differentiable, but `torch.clamp` is.
- To ensure the process works, we define an optimization objective via normalized cross-correlation (NCC): the optimal window length will be that which matches a reference. We implement NCC via `conv1d`.
- Optimize via plain gradient descent, ensure to zero gradients after each step to avoid gradding the grads

Suppose we start with `N=129` and optimum is `N_ref=160`. Results:

[image]

Code at [Github](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/StackExchangeAnswers/blob/main/SignalProcessing/Q81624%20-%20STFT%2C%20optimization%20-%20Optimize%20window%20length%20for%20STFT/main.py).

Comment: Great!! I did not know it's already implemented in pytorch. Many many thanks!

Comment: @JXuan Glad it helped, also added $\sigma$ case. If the problem's solved, consider [voting & accepting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icF0X.png).

Comment: Thanks for adding the σ case. For STFT, the window size is supposed to be the power of 2, instead of any real numbers, isn't it? If so, one could not just autodiff the win of Hann/Hamming window directly (because it is not differentiable)?

Comment: I got a reply from the contributors who implemented the torch stft and window functions in the Pytorch forum. They said 'The window size is not immediately trainable, although you could implement your own method of updating it.'

Comment: @JXuan Window can be of any length, power of 2 is typically for computational reasons. Yes, tuning something like width of Hanning will be harder, but is certainly doable. [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/ssqueezepy/_stft.py) has a torch implementation, but a key step isn't differentiable (`buffer` via CuPy) so it must be implemented via PyTorch - alternatively, code [here](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/issues/60) can be ported easily to torch (though needs optimizing)

Comment: I just looked into `buffer` in your repo. I think I need to find a continuous proxy of window length there or some other parameters where backpropogation could take place. Thanks for sharing your implementations. I will wait a bit to see if others have any ideas to share.

Comment: @JXuan Added example for $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $N$ as a positive real number and use your formula for the Hann window, $w[n]$. Then the partial derivative of $w[n]$ with respect to $N$ will be:

$$\frac{\partial\,w[n]}{\partial N} = \begin{cases}
- \dfrac{\pi\,n\,\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{N - 1}n\right)}{{\left(N - 1\right)}^2} \qquad & 0 \le n \le N-1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise.} \\
\end{cases}$$

At integer $N$, $w[n]$ has a very simple, sparse length-$N$ discrete Fourier transform (DFT). With non-integer $N$ that quality is lost, but  also I don't know that you would need that quality in our application.

Comment: Thanks for contributing the idea! What kind of quality loss do you mean specifically?

Comment: By "quality" I mean that "distinguishing attribute" with the DFT.